# How can I change the text cursor speed in Microsoft Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, cursor

When I hold <kbd>→</kbd> or <kbd>←</kbd>  in a text, the cursor moves to the right of the left. I'd like to change that speed, especially the speed it takes to move beyond the first character (which is much slower than the other characters).

Everything I could find so far pertain to the mouse pointer speed:

[image]

The following setting shows cursor speed, but instead affects the mouse pointer speed:

[image]

Comment: Microsoft is trying to confuse you by calling the "mouse pointer" a "cursor". Gotta love ambiguity.

Comment: The text insertion point is the "caret" in Windows; if I search the start menu for "caret" in Windows 11, I get various "text cursor" settings suggested.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Press <kbd>Win</kbd> (aka the Windows key)

Type: "keyboard"

Choose the option "Keyboard - Control Panel"

[image]

Choose your preferred repeat delay (how long you have to hold a key until it starts repeating), and your preferred repeat rate (how quickly it repeats). You can test them in the textbox below.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! anyway to configure it for a given key only?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Not as far as I know. Maybe there is some external piece of software I do not know about.

Comment: [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) can probably do this.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any way to tweak this, but it feels like a kind of XY problem, so I try to provide a different solution.

Actually, if you want to browse through the text in a faster way, you can do so word by word, you can hold <kbd>Strg</kbd> while pressing <kbd>←</kbd>  or <kbd>→</kbd>. THis will go word by word instead of character by character.